# Relation between binomials

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

how can I prove that the following relation is true:

$$\binom{x-2}y+2\binom{x-2}{y-1}+\binom{x-2}{y-2}=\binom{x}y$$

Thank you for hints or references!

Marted

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Apply Pascal’s identity twice:

$$\binom{x}y=\binom{x-1}y+\binom{x-1}{y-1}=\ldots~?$$

**Added:** By the way, you can prove by induction on $n$ that if you apply Pascal’s identity $n$ times, you get the identity

$$\binom{x}y=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{x-n}{y-k}\;.$$

Pascal’s identity is the case $n=1$, and your exercise is the case $n=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what does the left hand side count? The first term is the number of ways of choosing $y$ out of $x-2$ items. Can you make a similar statement about the other two terms on the LHS? How is this equivalent to the right hand side?